# How to post a link to Event's feed?

Tags: php, events, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to post a link to an Event's feed but no matter what I try it turns up as a status update without the link.

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ you can post links/posts and statuses to the feed. I post to the /[eventid]/feed with an array containing 2 elements, 'link' and 'message', the same array when posted on the feed of a user appears properly in link form. Is this a facebook bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an open bug

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/320152154697289

I suggest you subscribe to that bug as well as mark it confirmed